# Help understanding this differential equation of a varying electromagnetic field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, radiation

I'm reading some lecture notes (we're studying blackbody radiation and are approaching Planck's formula) but I'm struggling to understand exactly what's being said.

So the lecture notes read as follows:

> Classically, $n(\lambda)$ is proportional to $\dfrac{1}{\lambda^4}$, where $n(\lambda)$ is the number of oscillators inside a cavity as a function of wavelength.
>   Start with an electromagnetic field inside a cavity, with the amplitude of the wave at the wall of the cavity being equal to zero.
>
> EM standing waves: $\dfrac{d^2E}{dx^2}+\dfrac{d^2E}{dy^2}+\dfrac{d^2E}{dz^2}=\dfrac{1}{c^2}\dfrac{d^2E}{dt^2}$, where $E$ is the variation of the electromagnetic field and $x,y,z$ are the standard coordinates. So the sum of these 3 is equal to the time variation of the electromagnetic field.
>
> $E=E_0\sin(\dfrac{n_1\pi x}{L}) \sin(\dfrac{n_2\pi y}{L})\sin(\dfrac{n_3\pi z}{L})\sin(\dfrac{2\pi ct}{\lambda})$, where $L$ is the size of the cavity and n is an integer. This makes sense because at the edge of the cavity (when $x,y,z=L$), $E=0$ because the sin components all become zero.
>
> Sub the equation for $E$ into the differential equation and solve to verify that you get the condition $n_1^2+n_2^2+n_3^2=\dfrac{4L^2}{\lambda^2}$
>
> How many in cavity: $N\approx (n_1^2+n_2^2+n_3^2)^\dfrac{3}{2}=\dfrac{1}{\lambda^3}$

I couldn't read the lecture notes very clearly so some of the variables may be wrong, for example in the differential equation I'm not sure if it is meant to be a 1 above the $c$.

My issue here is that I'm not sure what I am asked to do.

Am I expected to substitute $E$ into the differential equation, and then solve the differential equation? And if I solve it should I expect to get $n_1^2+n_2^2+n_3^2=\dfrac{4L^2}{\lambda^2}$?

Also, could anyone tell me what the final formula is? How many what? And how is it determined?

Comment: Yes, you're expected to substitute and verify.

Answer (score 2):

You're supposed to substitute
$$
E\left(x,y,z,t\right)=E_0 \sin\left(\frac{n_1\pi x}{L}\right) \sin\left(\frac{n_2\pi y}{L}\right)\sin\left(\frac{n_3\pi z}{L}\right)\sin \left(\frac{2\pi ct}{\lambda}\right)
$$
into 
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
0 &=& \left(\nabla^2 - \frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}\right) E\left(x,y,z,t\right) \\
&=& \left(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}+\frac{\partial^2}{\partial z^2}-\frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}\right) E\left(x,y,z,t\right)
\end{eqnarray}
$$
and show that you get
$$
n_1^2+n_2^2+n_3^2=\frac{4L^2}{\lambda^2}
$$

Comment: Is there a difference between dE/dx and the symbols you have used?

Comment: $E\left(x,y,z,t\right)$ is a multivariable function, so that's why I have partial derivatives such as $\partial E / \partial x$ (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_derivative) instead of total derivatives such as $dE / dx$.